# Crashing android app on an sql query

Tags: java, android, sql

In this function I am trying to get the amount of rows in my Table .

```
public int getSetCount(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " +KEY_SET_ID+" * FROM "+TABLE_SETS;
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    return mcursor.getInt(0);

}
```

The logCat prints out something like this

```
   sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "FROM": syntax error
```

In this function I am going to find the name with a given ID .

```
public String getSetName (int ID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SETS+" WHERE "+KEY_SET_ID+" =? "+ID, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(0);
}
```

What is wrong with these functions , tell me please ? According all the forums and tutorials I am doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your SQL statement is not correctly written. Simply change the following line:

```
   String query = "SELECT " +KEY_SET_ID+" * FROM "+TABLE_SETS;
```

to:

```
String query = "SELECT " +KEY_SET_ID+" FROM "+TABLE_SETS;
```

Comment: I tried it but in the `getSetCount()` function there is no any error but it returns a false value . But in the `getSetName` there is still an error

Comment: Replace with this: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SETS+" WHERE "+KEY_SET_ID+" = "+ID, null);

Comment: So now there are no any errors , but the returned values of both functions are false :)

Comment: Well that depends on what data you are asking. Maybe they are empty. btw you should accept the answer if useful.

Comment: oh , sorry , only getSetCount() returns a false value